# How to put function Wordpress plugin Into Shortcode (One User Avatar)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I'm trying to figure out if I can insert this piece of code into a wordpress shortcode in functions.php

```
<p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-upload-button' : 'wpua-upload-button-existing' ); ?>">
                <input name="wpua-file" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-file' : 'wpua-file-existing' ); ?>" type="file" />

                <button type="submit" class="button" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-upload' : 'wpua-upload-existing' ); ?>" name="submit" value="<?php esc_html_e( 'Upload', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?>">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Upload', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?>
                </button>
            </p>
```

The piece of code is part of a plugin, this is the file: https://github.com/onedesigns/one-user-avatar/blob/main/includes/class-wp-user-avatar.php#L253

Could some good Samaritan take a look and give me directions on how to move? Sorry, but I'm new to codes, I don't have many skills and I'm a fan.

**Edit**: I modified the code in this way following the advice of the users that were given to me in the comments. The button is displayed correctly, but if I choose the image and click on load the saves are not carried out.

```
//CUSTOM SHORTCODE
function short_shortcode() {
 
 //Global
 global $current_user;
 
 $user = $current_user;
 
 ob_start();
?>
<form>
 <p id="<?php echo esc_attr(('add-new-user' == $user) ? 'wpua-upload-button' : 'wpua-upload-button-existing'); ?>">
   <input name="wpua-file" id="<?php echo esc_attr(('add-new-user' == $user) ? 'wpua-file' : 'wpua-file-existing'); ?>" type="file" />

   <button type="submit" class="button" id="<?php echo esc_attr(('add-new-user' == $user) ? 'wpua-upload' : 'wpua-upload-existing'); ?>" name="submit" value="<?php esc_html_e('Upload', 'one-user-avatar'); ?>">
     <?php esc_html_e('Upload', 'one-user-avatar'); ?>
   </button>
 </p>
</form> 
<?php
 return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('short', 'short_shortcode');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make wordpress shortcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311453/how-to-make-wordpress-shortcode)

Comment: @bitski Thanks for your intervention, I just read the post, I think it is something different from what I am trying to do. I managed to put the piece of code in the shortcode, it just doesn't work, the button doesn't perform any action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to the problem. For anyone interested here it is below. What I did was add some variables to the **global** found from https://github.com/onedesigns/one-user-avatar/blob/main/includes/class-wp-user-avatar-shortcode.php as suggested by the author of the plugin. (Some may not be needed, but I have included them as I will be extending the shortcode functionality in the future).

After that, I introduced the following function: `do_action( 'wpua_update', $valid_user->ID );` (always taken from the file I linked above).

Finally I added the code I was interested in the form tags and in `ob_start ();` - `return ob_get_clean();`

Furthermore, in the html code taken by the plugin it was necessary to add a few lines of php for the form to save everything.
`<? php wp_nonce_field ('update-user_'. $ user-> ID); ?>` `<? php submit_button (__ ('Update Profile', 'one-user-avatar')); ?>`

Here is the final working code

```
//SHORTCODE UPLOAD BUTTON ONE-USER-AVATAR
function short_shortcode() {
    
//Global
global   $wpua_force_file_uploader, 
         $show_avatars, 
         $wpua_shortcode, 
         $wp_user_avatar, 
         $all_sizes, 
         $blog_id, 
         $post, 
         $wpdb, 
         $current_user, 
         $wp_user_avatar, 
         $wpua_allow_upload, 
         $wpua_edit_avatar, 
         $wpua_functions;   

//Default user is current user
$user = $current_user;

//Function
do_action( 'wpua_update', $user->ID );

  ob_start();
?>
    <form id="wpua-edit-<?php echo esc_attr( $user->ID ); ?>" class="wpua-edit" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p id="<?php echo esc_attr(('add-new-user' == $user) ? 'wpua-upload-button' : 'wpua-upload-button-existing'); ?>">
         <input name="wpua-file" id="<?php echo esc_attr(('add-new-user' == $user) ? 'wpua-file' : 'wpua-file-existing'); ?>" type="file" />
         <button type="submit" class="button" id="<?php echo esc_attr(('add-new-user' == $user) ? 'wpua-upload' : 'wpua-upload-existing'); ?>" name="submit" value="<?php esc_html_e('Upload', 'one-user-avatar'); ?>">
         <?php esc_html_e('Upload', 'one-user-avatar'); ?></button>
        </p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user_' . $user->ID ); ?>
        <?php submit_button( __( 'Update Profile', 'one-user-avatar' ) ); ?>
    </form>
        
<?php
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('short', 'short_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture and return the output.  Here is how you can do that:

```
<?php

function short_shortcode() {
  ob_start();
?>
  <p id="<?php echo esc_attr(('add-new-user' == $user) ? 'wpua-upload-button' : 'wpua-upload-button-existing'); ?>">
    <input name="wpua-file" id="<?php echo esc_attr(('add-new-user' == $user) ? 'wpua-file' : 'wpua-file-existing'); ?>" type="file" />

    <button type="submit" class="button" id="<?php echo esc_attr(('add-new-user' == $user) ? 'wpua-upload' : 'wpua-upload-existing'); ?>" name="submit" value="<?php esc_html_e('Upload', 'one-user-avatar'); ?>">
      <?php esc_html_e('Upload', 'one-user-avatar'); ?>
    </button>
  </p>
<?php
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('short', 'short_shortcode');
```

More info  here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output

Comment: Thanks for your intervention. I followed your suggestion, the button is there but it doesn't work. It takes no action. I have read the documentation you left in the link, but I was unable to conclude anything. What can be the reason why no action is taken? Maybe I need to call some action? Sorry for my lack of skill, I hope there is more I can do.

Comment: how are you implementing the shortcode?

Comment: The variable `$user` does not currently exist in the scope of this function. It would either need to be passed in via shortcode attributes, or determined by some WP function call or something.

Comment: @mikerojas I put the code you wrote me in the functions.php file. Basically it was what I had done even before posting the question only I hadn't added the ob_start (); at the beginning and return ob_get_clean (); in the end.

Comment: @CBroe Here we have done almost the same thing, just with a different part of the plugin code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70278884/how-to-put-part-of-php-code-into-wordpress-shortcode/70280325?noredirect=1#comment124313028_70280325 This worked, but I don't know if I need to structure the new code the same way now.

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele well presumably exactly the same way then ...? `global $current_user; $user = $current_user;`

Comment: @CBroe I just added the variable to the global, also I added the opening and closing form tags because I saw it is the same in the original html output as well. However, the button still doesn't work, I don't know if need pass some other variable or action. I checked the plugin files but by myself I can't figure out which ones to select.

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele what form are we talking about here? The file you linked to in the question does not appear to create any form, so that must be coming from outside of it, presumably. I'm guessing it probably manipulates a user update form, to insert the avatar field into that. I can't tell you whether what you want here will work in such a simple way - you would need to at least re-create the form, pointing to the same target URL as the original.

Comment: But if you just send the avatar image file upload, then the validation applied to all other fields of that form might probably fail. So you would have to send all those other necessary values as hidden fields then ...

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the suggestions, I appreciate it. I assumed it worked with form tags, but I don't know if it actually does. With console google You can see the output here: https://motustrength.it/elementor-33122/ this is a test page of my website. The form you see to upload the avatar belongs to the plugin. What I would like to do is just take the input file with the upload button and put it inside the shortcode. The piece of code I posted here is just that button, but I can't figure out how to make it work in the shortcode.